# Перенести логирование в формат JSON

Tags: java, json, логирование, ant

Вот аппендер для записи логов в файл (кусок кода из logback.xml):

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>logs/ps_gate_server.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
       <Pattern>%d{dd-MM-yyyy} %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-19.19t] [%-5p] [%-1.40X{OperationName};%-1.10X{ClientID};%-1.20X{PayID}] %m%n </Pattern>
    </encoder> 
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <FileNamePattern>logs/ps_gate_server.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.zip</FileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
        
        <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
      </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
      </rollingPolicy>
</appender>
```

Как видно, encoder у меня ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder и все работает. Мне нужно перенести логи, записываемые в файл, в формат JSONL. Для этого я меняю класс encoder на net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder:

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>logs/ps_gate_server.log</file>
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
       <Pattern>%d{dd-MM-yyyy} %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-19.19t] [%-5p] [%-1.40X{OperationName};%-1.10X{ClientID};%-1.20X{PayID}] %m%n </Pattern>
    </encoder> 
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <FileNamePattern>logs/ps_gate_server.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.zip</FileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
        
        <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
      </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
      </rollingPolicy>
</appender>
```

После чего, при запуске программы, в каталоге logs программа даже не создает файл ps_gate_server.log. Подскажите если кто знает. Все необходимые jar файлы имеются.